# What is the probability C was the one with the wrong answer?

Tags: probability, statistics

Students A, B and C each independently answer a question on a test. The probability of getting the correct answer is 0.9 for A, 0.7 for B and 0.4 for C. If two of them get the correct answer, what is the probability C was the one with the wrong answer?

Comment: Have you studied conditional probability and Bayes' theorem? What have you tried?

Comment: It will be good to see that you tried to solve the problem. :)

Comment: Is it preassumed that at least one of them gave an incorrect answer? I ask that because you say: '...*was* the one with the wrong answer'  as if it is certain that one of them gave an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We interpret "two got the right answer" as meaning "exactly two."

Let $A,B,C$ be the events that, respectively, A, B, C get the right answer, and let $A',B',C'$ be the events that A, B, C get the wrong answer. Let $T$ be the event that exactly two got the right answer. We want $\Pr(C'|T)$.
By the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(C'|T)=\frac{\Pr(C'\cap T)}{\Pr(T)}.$$
We want to calculate the two probabilities on the right.

We have $\Pr(C'\cap T)=\Pr(A\cap B\cap C')=(0.9)(0.7)(0.6)$.

Also, $\Pr(T)=\Pr(A\cap B\cap C')+\Pr(A\cap B'\cap C)+\Pr(A'\cap B\cap C)$.

Comment: You got the denominator right, something went wrong when you calculated the numerator, it is $0.378$. The ratio is about $0.7354$.

Comment: You are welcome. Calculator slippage like that happens. It is one reason I don't like "exact answer" questions.